# Displaying latest news for each in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to display only 3 news in each category to display the last 3 news that were added.

Class **category**:

```php
class category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function articles(){
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class)->limit(3)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
      }
  
}
```

Class **Article**:

```php
class Article extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(category::class);
    }
  
}

$categories = category::with('articles')->limit(3)->get();
$articles = Article::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

return response()->view('news.index', compact('categories','articles'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **whereHas**

```
$categories = category::whereHas('articles', function($query){
        return $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(3);
    })->get();

return view('news.index', compact('categories'));
```

Comment: to get articles from categories $categories->articles

Answer (score 0):

By using latest()

```
$categories = category::whereHas('articles', function($query){
        return $query->latest()->take(3);
    })->get();

return view('news.index', compact('categories'));
```